# How to know if a file on a server is already opened by other user?

Tags: file-sharing, windows-server, lock

We are storing files an a network server (`Windows Server`) for accessing them in the team.

This works well with Microsoft Office - if I want to open a file which is already opened by some other user, I get a warning message and the option to open it read-only.

However, we are also using an open source software where this does not work.
Several user can open the same file simultaneously this leads to problems e. g. in the following scenario:

- user 1 opens a file (lets call it version "v1") and modifies it without saving
- user 2 opens the file from the server, which is still v1 and also starts modifying
- now user 1 saves his changes to the server and creates v2
- now user 2 saves his changes, creates v3 and the changes of user 1 (v2) are lost!

We can not use `svn` or other version control tools (too complicated), so I wonder if there is a standard mechanism which could be implemented in the software to prevent those problems.

How do other programs solve that?
Is there a kind of "file locked" information which has to be switched "on" as soon as someone opens the file?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this Wikipedia article on Windows File Locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows) which gives a good overview and starting point for your investigation.

Depending on your amount/type of data you could concider creating a small and inexpensive Sharepoint Foundation server as it has some easy to use basic document management function which will prevent intercede updates.

How does your open source software work?

Comment: thanks a lot! The keyword "file locking" is already very helpful. We have a SharePoint Standard Server running already but not all files are on there yet and not all colleagues are familiar with it, so it sounds like a little overkill... **What do you mean by "How does your open source software work"?**

Comment: For instance - does your open source software create the file on local computer and then copies it over (which might explain why it does not consider locked files). I am asking as MS Word and Excel automatically locks files and provides a alert that the file is in use, which are worked on directly on a Windows file server.

Comment: thanks for the explanation - I have no idea, I'm just a user but not a developer, but I'll try to find out.